# Angular LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-local-storage

Hi guys i am trying to save some information with localStorage in angular, i injected $window to my service and i created a factory call $localStorage

```
.factory('$localStorage', ['$window', function($window) {
        return {
            store: function(key, value) {
            $window.localStorage[key] = value;
            },
            get: function(key, defaultValue) {
            return $window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue;
            },
            storeObject: function(key, value) {
            $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
            },
            getObject: function(key,defaultValue) {
            return JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key] ||     defaultValue);
            }
        }
        }])
```

i have other factory where i make us of the localStorage factory in order to save some favorites

```
factory("favoriteFactory", ["$resource", "baseURL", "$localStorage", function($resource, baseURL, $localStorage) {
        var favFac = {};
        var favorites = $localStorage.getObject("favorites", "[]");

        favFac.addToFavorites = function(index) {
            for (var i = 0; i < favorites.length; i++) {
                if (favorites[i].id == index)
                    return;
            }

            $localStorage.storeObject("favorites", {id: index});
            //favorites.push({id: index});
        };

        favFac.deleteFromFavorites = function (index) {
            for (var i = 0; i < favorites.length; i++) {
                if (favorites[i].id == index) {
                    favorites.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        }

        favFac.getFavorites = function () {
            return favorites;
        };

        return favFac;
    }])
```

the problem is when i add a favorite item, it replaces itself in my array, instead of adding a new one to the array,

i really aprecciate the help
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing wrong while storing. You are replacing an array with a single item. One more thing to note that, Array.prototype.push() return the length of the collection.

```
enter code herefavFac.addToFavorites = function(index) {
        for (var i = 0; i < favorites.length; i++) {
            if (favorites[i].id == index)
                return;
        }
        favorites.push({id: index})
        $localStorage.storeObject("favorites", favorites);
        //favorites.push({id: index});
    };
```

Comment: Array.prototype.push() does not return the item. it returns the length

Comment: @mJunaidSalaat Thank you Junaid, I actually tried to push `4` in an array `[1,2,3]` and it returned me 4, so I thought it returns item. Thanks for correction. but bad for negative vote :P

Comment: No problem. You can edit your answer and I'll remove the negative vote and at first you didn't answered the question correctly that's why I made an answer but you edited it later. :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change `addToFavorites` method like

```
favFac.addToFavorites = function(index) {
            for (var i = 0; i < favorites.length; i++) {
                if (favorites[i].id == index)
                    return;
            }

            favorites.push({id: index});
            $localStorage.storeObject("favorites", favorites);

        };
```

Now it will add an item first then save your array into the local storage.

Answer (score 0):

As an advice I suggest you to use [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) which enables you to add or remove item from localStorage as simples as a single command:

```
$localStorage.favorites = [];
```

That's it and now you have favorites list in localStorage and any time you modify this array you will get results directly on localStorage.

```
$localStorage.favorites.push(newItemToAdd); // this adds a item.
$localStorage.favorites = $localStorage.favorites
    .filter((v, i) => i !== indexOfItemToDelete); // removes item.
```